# Can someone please explain in beginner terms how this Ordinal number function works?

Tags: javascript, ordinal

```
var getOrdinal = function(n) {
var s = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"],
v = n % 100;
return n + (s[(v - 20) % 10] || s[v] || s[0]);
};
console.log(getOrdinal(1));
```

Comment: Yet another case of "clever" code. Which part in particular do you need help with?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is that the numbers 1-10 and 20-30, 30-40 etc follow the same pattern. The teens don't follow the pattern - 11th, 12th, 13th, 14th etc up to 20.

v is set to the remainder of n divided by 100 - in other words the last two digits of the number n thats passed in. Thats because the ordinal ending is the same for every hundred.

to work out the extension there are three clauses in the or statement - the first of these that evaluates - by indexing into the array with a value between 0 and 3 (inclusive) - will be appended onto the original number passed.

lets break each of these down:

s[(v - 20) % 10] - this takes care of the case where the number is over 20 by subtracting 20 from the number and then finding the remainder after dividing by ten. e.g. 32 evaluates to 2 and returns 'nd'. If the number doesn't end in 1,2 or 3 or is less than 20 this clause won't evaluate and we pass onto checking the next clause

s[v] - this takes care of the case where the number is 0,1,2 or 3 by directly indexing into the array to get 'th','st','nd' or 'rd' respectively

s[0] - finally this takes care of all the other numbers

Its key to note two things:

1. Javascript evaluates an invalid index into an array as false
2. Ors are evaluated in order and the checking stops on the first match

HTH

Answer (score 0):

```
var s = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"],
```

Declare an array called s that contains 4 strings.

```
v = n % 100;
```

And, another variable called v who's value is the result of the passed in argument (n) modulus 100 (remainder of n / 100)

```
return n + (s[(v - 20) % 10] || s[v] || s[0]);
```

The function should return the evaluated value of n + the first of the following array elements that do not evaluate to a "falsy" value (0, "", undefined, null, false): the v-20 indexed element of the array, the v indexed element of the array or the first element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

to maybe get a better understnding of the code

```
var getOrdinal = function(n) {
    var s = ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"],
    v = n % 100;
    return n + (s[(v - 20) % 10] || s[v] || s[0]);
};

var test = function(n) {
    v = n % 100;
    console.log(n, (v - 20) % 10, v, 0, getOrdinal(n))
};
for(i = 0; i < 130; i++) test(i);
```

this will output each "part" of the funky return statement separately - so you may be able to see what is happening yourself